# PHP create a temp Table and use it in the Next query (SQL Server 2008 from Microsoft)

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following problem. I hava a huge DB and a long query. To speed up the DB request i use a temporary table, which works perfectly on Server Managment Studio. Now I want to put this query in my php code which doesn't work.

The Code looks like this

EXAMPLE:

```
$sql="
/*First Select and creating the tmp table:*/

SELECT data, data2, data3 INTO #tmp
FROM dbo.data
INNER JOIN ...
WHERE ...  ;

/*Second Select wich is the main select:*/

SELECT data, data2, data3
FROM #tmp tmp
INNER JOIN otherTableOnServer
WHERE ....

UNION

SELECT data, data2, data3 
FROM #tmp tmp
INNER JOIN otherTableOnServer
INNER JOIN otherTableOnServer2
LEFT OUTER JOIN otherTableOnServer3
....

";

$result=sqlsrv_query($conn2,$sql);
            $content=array();
            while($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($result,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $content[]=$row;
}
```

and so on.

Notice: 
The php code works fine, only if I use the query in the code it doesn't work.
There is no error message, the page that is created go trough, but without the results from the query.

I use SQL Server 2008 R2 and the current version of PHP.

Comment: What is the actual version? Did you mean the most recent version?

Comment: sqlsrv functions don't normally output errors. They return boolean false on failure, and you're not checking for that at all. a very very minimal error handling system would be `$result = sqlsrv_query(...) or die(sqlsrv_errors(SQLSRV_ERR_ALL))`

Comment: can you implement a stored procedure on the server, which the PHP file would call?

Comment: I use php 5.5 if that was the question. Thanks for the error handler, I took over an existing Project and I'm not used to php so I implement the error handler as soon as I can. I can't give you any orginal codes examples, I hope that the example that i posted is good enough to understand my problem, if not i will try another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single # indicates a local temp table which can only be accessed from within the session that created it.

Append ## instead of # to make the temp table global and accessible from outside the session that created it.